# Scroll is neither recording nor playing back in Monkytalk(ios)

Tags: monkeytalk

In my iOS mobile app, the feature of scrolling i.e pull down to add task is not working. MonkeyTalk is not recording and playing back this feature.I have used ScrollToRow command but of no use, So kindly help me to sort it out.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`Scroller * Scroll 0 200`

Does this command not work for you?